# How to append data to a Slice that is formatted by a Nested Struct

Tags: go, struct, append, slice

I am trying to append some data into a slice based off of my struct.

In attempting to do this, I tried splitting up my struct into two separate ones. This was unsuccessful. Every-time I tried to append the slice, i would get an error: `missing type in composite literal`. I tried googling this but i can't seem to figure it out.

```golang
// Separate File in types folder
type Item struct {
    ID                 string `json:"id"`
    Item               string `json:"item"`
    ProductDescription []ProductDescription
}

// Separate File in types folder
type ProductDescription struct {
    ShortDescription    string `json:"short_description"`
}


//Items Slice holds ItemsDB
var Items []types.Item

func ItemsDB() {
    Items = append(Items,
        types.Item{
            ID:                 "1",
            Item:               "fruit",
            ProductDescription: {
                ShortDescription: "banana",
            },
        },
        types.CoreItem{
            ID:                 "1",
            Item:               "dairy",
            ProductDescription: {
                ShortDescription, "milk",
            },
        },
    )
}
```

An expected result would be:

```
{

{"id": "1", "item": "fruit", "product_descriptions": {"short_description": "banana"},

{"id": "1", "item": "fruit", "product_descriptions": {"short_description": "banana"}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ProductDescription` is an array, your syntax is initializing a struct. Try this:

```
ProductDescription: []types.ProductDescription{
   {  ShortDescription: "banana"}
 }
```

Comment: — I tried doing the above like the following but keep getting `undefined: ProductDescription`
`func ItemsDB() {
    Items = append(Items,
        types.Item{
            ID:                 "1",
            Item:               "fruit",
            ProductDescription: []ProductDescription{
                {ShortDescription: "banana"},
            },
        }
}`

Comment: You need to qualify it with the package name just like you're doing with `Item`.

Comment: Looks like ProductDescription is in types package. I fixed the answer to include that.